# C++ bookkeeping line segments and calling its members

Tags: c++, class, pointers, vector, struct

maybe it's something very trivial, but I didn't find anything when searching. Let me demonstrate what I want on the following example. Let's have classes, V2, LineSegment and Curve:

```
class V2 {
public:
    long double x, y;
    V2(long double xx = 0, long double yy = 0);
    friend V2 operator+... //not important
};

V2::V2(long double X, long double Y) {
    x = X; y = Y;
}

class LineSegment {
public:
    int s1, s2;
    LineSegment(int seg1 = 0, int seg2 = 0);
};

LineSegment::LineSegment(int seg1, int seg2) {
    s1 = seg1; s2 = seg2;
}

class Curve {
public:
    vector<V2> p;
    vector<LineSegment> s;
    Curve(vector<V2> po = {}, vector<int> seg = {});
};

Curve::Curve(vector<V2> poi, vector<LineSegment> seg) {
    p = poi; s = seg;
}
```

**My first question** is: I want there to be a callable parameter **n** in Curve, like this: (Curve c) `c.s[whatever].n` to get normal vector of the segment, where `n = c.p[c.s[whatever].s2] - c.p[c.s[whatever].s1]` (which is, again, 2D point, but its meaning is vector in 2D plane). To put it simply: it is not needed for LineSegment to remember its normal vector, in fact, it is really undesirable as the normal will change if a point is moved. If I store LineSegment like this (only indices or pointers), it can't really know what points are doing in some other structure.

**My second question** is: LineSegment on its own is useless, those integer numbers don't mean anything unless there is some vector of points so it can actually point to its members. Is there any way to bookkeep such structure without mess like this? I would like to rather use pointers.

I think that the second question has something to do with storing just pointers. I really do need a hint on the first issue though...

Comment: I think for question 2 the crucial point is the choice of representation of the curve. Am I correct to assume that `seg2 = seg1 + 1` for all `LineSegment`s (i.e. the `poi` vector is sorted w.r.t. the parametrization of the curve)?

Comment: No, unfortunately, that's not correct. I want to use this to describe a region, ie its interior made of polygons (triangles) and a boundary made of line segments. Boundary of a region might or might not be one single curve (only in the case of simply connected region). This bookkeeping is very important as it gets very messy every time I want to connect two points, add a new point or delete a point and corresponding segments that the point belonged to. I will want a similar thing for interiors and triangles (faces), just with three points instead of two.

Comment: Let's see if I understand this now: The `poi` vector you pass to the curve doesn't only contain the points of the curve, but a superset of the points of the curve. The line segments then have indices into the `poi` vector to describe the points that actually are actually on the curve.

Comment: EXACTLY! So if I have 5 points p[0], .. p[4], I can connect them with segments, for example s[0] would be 3, 4, s[1] would be 1, 0 and s[2] would be 0, 3. Three segments used.